# Display image stored as datatype "image" in MySQL DB

Tags: asp.net

How can I display images stored as datatype "image" in MySQL using asp.net? `pimage` is the field in the DB that stores the image.

```
SqlDataReader reader = rou.ExecuteReader(); 

while (reader.Read())
        {

            sb.AppendLine("Pizza ID: " + reader["pid"].ToString() + "<br/>" + "Pizza Name:" + reader["pname"].ToString()
                + "<br/>" + "Pizza Desc:" + reader["pdesc"].ToString() + "<br/>" + "Psize:" + reader["psize"].ToString()
                + "<br/>" + "P Type:" + reader["ptype"].ToString() + "<br/>" + "P IMage" + reader["pimage"].Tostring() + "<br/>" + "P Cost" + reader["pcost"].ToString() + "<br/>" + "Buy" + "<br/>");


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know any HTML? Here is the trick - start with that.

Generally: do not load the image, load a reference string then have a handler returning the image data. Same as with static pages.